# How to modify each line of a text?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file which looks like this (it can have more than 2 lines):

```
$ cat /tmp/temp.txt 
;user1;1.1.1.1;DB1;SELECT;
;userX;2.2.2.2;DB4;SELECT;
```

And I want to change it like this:

```
user: user1 address: 1.1.1.1 db: DB1 right: SELECT
user: userX address: 2.2.2.2 db: DB4 right: SELECT
```

I think the simplest way to do it would be with the `read` function:

```
!/bin/bash

filename='/tmp/temp.txt'
while read ; do
  user=$(cut -d";" -f2 /tmp/temp.txt)
  address=$(cut -d";" -f3 /tmp/temp.txt)
  database=$(cut -d";" -f4 /tmp/temp.txt)
  right=$(cut -d";" -f5 /tmp/temp.txt)

 echo "user:$user address:$address database:$database right:$right"

done < $filename
```

The output of the script is:

```
user:user1
userX address:1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2 database:DB1
DB4 right: SELECT
SELECT
user:user1
userX address:1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2 database:DB1
DB4 right: SELECT
SELECT
```

I would like to have in my ouput the same number of lines as I have in the input file.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `sed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `awk`:

```
$ awk -F ';' '{ print "user:", $2, "address:", $3, "db:", $4, "right:", $5 }' your_file
```

This splits each line of the file up on semicolons, and then prints out the desired columns in your desired output format.

Comment: Probably a bit cleaner to write `print "user:", $2, "address"...`, but that's a minor style point.

Comment: @WilliamPursell You know, I think I agree.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with bash, you're on the right track, but you're doing too much work:

```
filename='/tmp/temp.txt'
while read ; do
  user=$(cut -d";" -f2 /tmp/temp.txt)
  address=$(cut -d";" -f3 /tmp/temp.txt)
  database=$(cut -d";" -f4 /tmp/temp.txt)
  right=$(cut -d";" -f5 /tmp/temp.txt)

 echo "user:$user address:$address database:$database right:$right"

done < $filename
```

1. You're using `while read; do ...; done < file` kind of correctly, but then you're not using the data you read inside the loop. You have 4 cut commands inside the loop, so you're processing the whole file 4 times for each line in the file.
2. `read` without any variable names stores the data in the default `$REPLY` variable. You *could* do

   ```
   filename='/tmp/temp.txt'
   while read ; do
     user=$(echo "$REPLY" | cut -d";" -f2)
     address=$(echo "$REPLY" | cut -d";" -f3)
     database=$(echo "$REPLY" | cut -d";" -f4)
     right=$(echo "$REPLY" | cut -d";" -f5)
     ...
   ```

   but that's still using external commands for something the shell can do natively.
3. use the `IFS` variable to help you parse each line: you have semicolon-separated data, so you can do this:

   ```
   while IFS=";" read -r empty user address database right empty; do
       echo "user:$user address:$address database:$database right:$right"
   done < $filename
   ```

   Note the "empty" variable placeholders to hold the data before the first semicolon, and after the last one.

Comment: thx, sounds like read was not the simpliest way to do it, i really like you proposition with IFS

Answer (score 1):

With sed, replacing semicolons one by one, from left to right:

```
$ sed 's/;/user: /;s/;/ address: /;s/;/ db: /;s/;/ right: /;s/;//' infile
user: user1 address: 1.1.1.1 db: DB1 right: SELECT
user: userX address: 2.2.2.2 db: DB4 right: SELECT
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=";"
  OFS=": "
}
val{
  sub(/: $/,"",val)
  print val
  val=""
}
{
  $1="user"
  $2=$2 " address"
  $3=$3 " db"
  $4=$4" right"
  val=$0
}
END{
  if(val){
    sub(/: $/,"",val)
    print val
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: That's way more complicated than it needs to be; see my answer.

Comment: @Shawn, yeah but I actually considered in case there are more fields than what OP didn't want to change then better NOT to hard code all fields.